# Install graphite in docker on raspberry pi returns 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: docker, nginx, graphite

I installed graphite in a docker container on a raspberry pi like it is described here: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
It is basically just one command and everything else is done automatically.
I can also see that the container is running however when I try to access the web front-end I get an error message "502 Bad Gateway".
Can anyone support?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about software development. This is probably better over at http://superuser.com (or perhaps https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, but the question isn't really Pi specific).

Comment: What do the `docker logs graphite` say?  502 Bad Gateway typically means nginx/apache can not reach the upstream service (the graphite process).  I assume the process did not start successfully.  I was able to start up the container and access the web ui locally using the exact command in the link you provided, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Using suggested `docker logs graphite`, I was able to get the following error:

> Fatal Python error: init_interp_main: can't initialize time

I found a working fix for this:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.3-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.3-2_armhf.deb
```